# WiX - Install Windows Service and give permissions

Tags: .net, windows-services, wix, windows-installer

We are required to give a user permissions to Start, Stop, and Query status of an installed service.

In WiX 2.0, this xml would have worked:

```
<ServiceInstall
    Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess"
    Name="$(var.ServiceName)" DisplayName="$(var.ServiceName)" Description="Our service description"
    Start="demand" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="ignore" Interactive="no">
    <Permission User="Everyone" ServiceQueryStatus="yes" ServiceStart="yes" ServiceStop="yes" />
</ServiceInstall>
<ServiceControl Id="StopService" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="$(var.OmniVpnServiceName)" Wait="yes" />
```

We're using WiX 3.0, and they removed the Service* attributes from the Permission element, and no longer allow it to be a child of a ServiceInstall element.

How do we get the same effect in WiX 3.0?

As an overview, we need:

Install a Service with:

- Manual startup
- Runs under Local System as "ownProcess"
- Non-interactive with desktop
- Stops on uninstall

Give the "Everyone" user access to:

- Start
- Stop
- Query Status

*On the installed service.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Documentation says use this inside the ServiceInstall element:

```
<util:PermissionEx
    User="Everyone"
    GenericAll="yes"
    ServiceChangeConfig="yes"
    ServiceEnumerateDependents="yes"
    ChangePermission="yes"
    ServiceInterrogate="yes"
    ServicePauseContinue="yes"
    ServiceQueryConfig="yes"
    ServiceQueryStatus="yes"
    ServiceStart="yes"
    ServiceStop="yes" />
```

I haven't tried it

util namespace is `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"`

Comment: Can you post the link to the documentation you're looking at?  I've been going to wix.sourceforge.net, and it's been lacking for a lot of things.

Comment: Actually found that in a forum, here is the link if you want to dig further and see what other gold you can find:

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=wix-users&max_rows=25&offset=18&style=nested&viewmonth=200809&viewday=26

Comment: I use the WiX.chm provided in each build. It's Index and Searching finds answers for me quickly.

Comment: to make the response full, remember to add the Reference to the WixUtilsExtension.dll

Comment: @SzymonSasin : The correct name of the dll to reference is WixUtilExtension.dll