# WiX - Trying to set the permissions of a service using util:PermissionEx and getting an Error 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.6, wix-extension

The question [WiX - Install Windows Service and give permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2381219/466321) is exactly what I am trying to do. First I have added the `UtilExtension` namespace like this:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```

Then I have added the following to the `ServiceInstall` element:

```
<util:PermissionEx
              User="Authenticated Users"
              GenericAll="yes"
              ServiceChangeConfig="yes"
              ServiceEnumerateDependents="yes"
              ChangePermission="yes"
              ServiceInterrogate="yes"
              ServicePauseContinue="yes"
              ServiceQueryConfig="yes"
              ServiceQueryStatus="yes"
              ServiceStart="yes"
              ServiceStop="yes" />
```

Finally the compiler provides me with the following error message:

> Error 1   The ServiceInstall element contains an unhandled extension
>   element 'util:PermissionEx'.  Please ensure that the extension for
>   elements in the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension'
>   namespace has been provided.

Is there something else I need to do to ensure the extension for the elements has been provided? How do I fix this?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that the xmlns needed to be added, I wasn't sure what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to add the reference to the WiX Util extension dll to your project.

1. Under your project, right-click *References*
2. Select Add *Reference*
3. Choose the *WixUtilExtension.dll* and select *Add*

Answer (score 4):

If you're still seeing the squiggle line:

[image]

Add the xmlns:util:

```
xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```